# Get total hits from a Full Text Search

Tags: mysql, sql, search

Is it possible to get the total amount of keyword hits from a Full Text search in Mysql?

```
SELECT id, description, SUM_TOTAL_KEYWORD_HITS
FROM table
WHERE MATCH (description) AGAINST('keyword1 keyword2')
```

Then have it return:

```
+----+---------------------+----------------------+
| ID | description         |    totalkeywordhits  |  
+----+---------------------+----------------------+
|  1 | Penny is a dog      | 2                    | 
|  2 | Gandalf is a human  | 1                    | 
+----+---------------------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

Possible selecting of total score of match clause

```
SELECT id, description, (SELECT MATCH(description) AGAINST('keyword1 keyword2')) AS score
FROM table
WHERE MATCH (description) AGAINST('keyword1 keyword2');
```

For keyword count, you would have to split keywords and match against everyone alone, for try :)